# how to use a function in the select input type

Tags: php, function, html-select

I need some help with using a function in a option value.
I just started using/learning functions and wrote this :

```
*function selectNew($dbcon) {
  $sql = 'SELECT id, item, comment, date, time, important FROM item ORDER BY ASC id';
  foreach ($dbcon->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['item'] . "\t";
    print $row['comment'] . "\t";
    print $row['date'] . "\n";
    print $row['time'] . "\n";
    print $row['important'] . "\n";
  }
}*
```

i want to use this in :

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Select by:</th><td><select>
      <option value="<?php selectNew ?>">Newest</option>
    </select></td></tr>
</table>
```

If i select this i want to echo the data from my database in ascending order by id.

Is this possible or do i need to do this in a other way?

Thanks,

Comment: Your function may return multiple rows. Also in your use case, you can't put multiple values in the value attribute, let alone multiple rows.

Comment: Use phpAdmin to run your query, and then look at the results. Also, create the plain HTML result you expect to see (rather than the one you show with the function call). Lastly, since you are learning, you should realize that when you call the function, you need to pass the arguments specified in the function declaration.

Comment: Thank you i tried it in phpmyadmin and found the problem !

Comment: Glad that worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to output your option tags from within the loop.

```
function selectNew($dbcon) {
  $sql = 'SELECT id, item, comment, date, time, important FROM item ORDER BY ASC id';
  foreach ($dbcon->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<option>";
    print $row['item'] . "\t";
    print $row['comment'] . "\t";
    print $row['date'] . "\n";
    print $row['time'] . "\n";
    print $row['important'] . "\n";
    echo "</option>";
  }
}

<table>
    <tr><th>Select by:</th><td><select>
      <?php selectNew($dbConn); ?>
    </select></td></tr>
</table>
```